# Makefile does not see h file even with -I specified

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

I can't get Makefile to compile with my header file in /usr/local/include.

Here is my test code below in test.c.

```
#include <uci.h>
void main(){
        struct uci_context *c;
        c = uci_alloc_context ();
}
```

Now running the command below works well and produce my binary correctly.

```
gcc test.c -o test -I/usr/local/include/uci -luci
```

But my Makefile below will not acknowledge the -I option.

```
CC=gcc
LIBS=-luci
INCL=-I/usr/local/include/uci

all: test

test: test.o
        $(CC) test.c -o test $(INCL) $(LIBS)
```

After running the make I get this.

```
gcc    -c -o test.o test.c
test.c:1:17: fatal error: uci.h: No such file or directory
 #include <uci.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'test.o' failed
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

If a relevant information this is being compiled on Raspbian Buster. The same Makefile was running well on OpenWRT.

Comment: The rule you have is to build `test` but you don't have an explicit rule to build `test.o.` Since the `test` rule depends on `test.o` make will first attempt to build `test.o`. And without an explicit rule it will use this implicit rule: `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c`. So try setting `CFLAGS` instead of `INCL`.

Comment: Also, note that it is arguably not good practice to explicit add `/usr/local/include/` into the include path. That is usually configured into `gcc` already. Instead, change your code to include relative to that path: `#include <uci/uci.h>`. If that is done the `-I` is not even needed.